# Is there a way to call a Redux Action from Cypress.io testing software?

Tags: redux, react-redux, cypress

react app. using redux and saga. have a large store and many actions tied to sagas. I need to do something simple.

Call my logout action from cypress. which should log the user out.

Due to frequent UI changes, i want something that just calls the action on the logout tests.

UPDATE:

im in react using MUI element. , have tried applying

```
<Typography data-cy="log-out" ......>Logout</Typography>
```

and calling it from the test

```
cy.get('data-cy="log-out"').click()
```

i get a console error in cypress

```
//Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-cy="log-out"
```

in some instances the element is hidden in a drop down in others it shown. im betting since its hidden sometimes, its not finding in the DOM based on the above method.

Comment: Could you have a hidden button that triggers logging out? That'd be cleaner. The alternative is attaching a function (which triggers the action) to the window object and calling that in cypress. I'm not sure that'd be the best solution

Comment: yeah its just a few different responsive navbars, some hide some dont, might be different ids to target the logout button, etc

Comment: You can add a data tag i.e. `<div data-cy="log-out">` then that'll always be the same id?

Comment: i'll try it and see if it works.. i can add that tag to 2 different logout buttons for example, then call it by id/class "log-out" in cypress??

Comment: You can call it by doing `cy.get('data-cy="log-out"').click()`

Comment: let me integrate, if it works ill let you answer for the points

Comment: cy.get('data-cy="log-out"').click()  //Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-cy="log-out"

Comment: `cy.get('[data-cy="log-out"]').click()` sorry left out the brackets for the attribute selector!

Comment: its finding it now, but giving error :  This element <h5.MuiTypography-root.makeStyles-sideNavContent-318.MuiTypography-h5.MuiTypography-colorInherit> is not visible because its parent <div.MuiBox-root.MuiBox-root-305.makeStyles-navigation-299> has CSS property: display: none. i dont supposed there is a way to force this thru? or am i going to have to wrtie some conditional code?

Comment: You should be able to use `.click({ force: true })` in that situation

Comment: works!!! add an answer if you want credit. thank you my friend. great new tool to use on cypress too... this data-cy attribute. much appreciated

Comment: Great! No worries, have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the generic data attribute as the selector as opposed to an id or class that is likely to change. Then, you can use `force` which will fire the event even if the element found is hidden through `display: none` etc.

i.e.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="log-out"]').click({ force: true })
```